# How to show files in File Explorer of Eclipse for phone connected with USB?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have connected my rooted phone using USB, adb is running as root and I still can't see anything in File Explorer in Eclipse, but when I run adb shell from command line I can list directories with ls and browse them.

How can I get File Explorer to work?

Answer (score 5):

Though i see it couple of months later,but if you still don't find it then here it is:
After opening your **Eclipse** select **DDMS** perspective.Then go..

**Window--> Show view--> File Explorer**

Answer (score 0):

EasyShell is an extension to Eclipse. It allows file manager.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell

If using Ubuntu, ExploreFS can also help.

http://www.junginger.biz/eclipse/

Comment: My real intention is using [SQLiteManager plugin](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/#comment-3252), so I need Eclipse File Explorer to work, but thanks :)