# Show data in file explorer of eclipse for phone connected with USB

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am developing with my phone connected with USB in eclipse and storing data in the sqlite database on my phone. I have installed the questoid sqlite manger plugin into eclipse and am using it so that I can browse the data in the sqlite database.

To get to the data I must go to /data/data/package_name/databases. However when I go to File Explorer and click on /data, a second directory of /data/data does not come up. When I click on the first /data, nothing comes up. My phone has also been rooted. How can I get to /data/data/package_name/databases?

I can get to /data/data/package_name/databases through the emulator but not when I am testing on my phone through USB.

I looked at this post, but it is not the same question: [How to show files in File Explorer of Eclipse for phone connected with USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413082/how-to-show-files-in-file-explorer-of-eclipse-for-phone-connected-with-usb)

Comment: Most of those data folders are naturally hidden to most OS's. Have you tried enable to see hidden folders for your OS?

Comment: It depends. Which operating systems are you using?

Comment: I just checked, I am using Windows 7 and had viewing hidden folders already enabled.

Comment: I also rooted my HTC One because someone thought that that could be a possible solution (read on a forum) to view the data but even after rooting my phone it still is the same and nothing comes up after i click on the first /data tab within file explorer.

Comment: I usually access the Databases for my apps using the Command Line Interface in the adb.

You can follow this post steps on how to access it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062187/get-sqlite-database-from-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Only your app can look in /data/data/your.package.name. No other app. No adb. If you want to have a look in the database file than copy it to external memory where everybody has access. Your app is the only one who can copy that file.